# Visual C++ 2008 Express Or Eclipse Ganymede With CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-c++, eclipse-cdt

I'm learning *C++*, and I want to know from those who are very good developers now: What is the best IDE, *Visual C++ 2008 Express* or *Eclipse Ganymede* with *CDT*? Remember that I'm using *Microsoft Windows Vista Ultimate*. Thanks!

The book that I'm reading is from Deitel: [C++ How to Program, 5/e](http://www.deitel.com/books/cpphtp5/), because I don't know if the code of the book supports *Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using both regularly now.

Visual studio is easier and more user friendly. I have issues with it though. They force you to do a number of things for reasons the benefit Microsoft and not you. It's free so you can't complain that much. Support is non existent but there's google for help.

Eclipse Gallileo does some difficult things startlingly well, but does some simple stuff startlingly badly. Such as when you compile if there's an error you get no visual indication. You have to open the problems window to see the errors. DOH! Eclipse is nearly as good as visual studio overall and is one of the best when using linux. The new version of the debugger has some very nice new features as well. Support is poor to non existent but there's google for help.

I tried codeblocks. The support was not very good to rude. I found it difficult to do anything serious with.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on Windows, MSVC++ 2008 Express is probably the one to go with, since it's the platform's native compiler. If you don't have any experience with Eclipse already, definitely go with MSVC. I've found Eclipse to be very counter-intuitive, but that's me, you may love it.

Comment: I've used Eclipse, because before i try to learn C++, i was learning Java, then i have some experience with Eclipse. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use codeblocks :) I like it a lot actually. Its interface is really easy to use.

I am having issues with MSVS right now which I will be posting a question about here in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation, i'm goig to try it!

Comment: I like it. It's free also so if you don't like it, oh well, just uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

Either will do you fine at this stage, but on balance I think you will find VS 2008 Express a little more straightforward unless you have much Eclipse experience.

That said, once you begin developing your OS you may find that you need to upgrade to the full (non-Express) version.

Comment: If i want to use the *Pro* version, i can buy only the VC++ or i have to buy all the VS?

Answer (score 0):

I use both Visual Studio 2005 Pro (at work) and Eclipse CDT (for personal projects).

I do prefer to use Eclipse because I program meanly Qt applications on Windows with it. The Qt integration module is really good (and available freely at http://qt.nokia.com/). 
Once you are there, you could give a try also to Qt's lightweight IDE: Qt Creator.

If you are going to do C++ GUI programming, I think you should definitively go with Eclipse CDT and the Qt Integration plugin. I've programmed (and suffering) several years of MFC before learning Qt and I will never go back!

Hope it helps!